# Formatting currency

Tags: c#, string, currency-formatting

i want to show $ to sales price and for this i done

```
<asp:Label ID="lblpriceValue" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("product_price")) %>'/>
```

but this is not showing $ or any other symbol before currency
so for temporary i have added $ symbol before label like

```
$<asp:Label ID="lblpriceValue" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("product_price")) %>'/>
```

but i know this is wrong because i want to set currency symbol according to country.

how can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourMoneyType.ToString("c");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need it in some data binding scenario, then it would be something like this:

```
<%# Eval("data_field", "{0:c}")%>
```

But, you need to make sure that you have set US globalization settings (or any other culture you want to show symbol for)  either in Control panel on your web server or, alternatively, you could specify it in web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Otherwise, you'll get a currency symbol based on the current web server locale, e.g. £, ¥, etc.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the locale using [`CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx):

```
value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Will display the $-sign...
```